# Does non-synthetic 10w30 motor oil contain sulphur?

Tags: oil

I ask this question as I plan on using 10W30 motor oil in my Jeep's manual transmission and need no sulphur added to the oil so that it is "yellow metal safe". I'm not looking to start a discussion around whether or not motor oil may be used in manual transmission but rather, looking for information on whether motor oil (synthetic or mineral) contains sulphur as an additive. I assume synthetic does not.

Answer (score 1):

Synthetic based oils do not typically contain sulphanates. Mobil, as an example recommend
Mobil 1 synthetic gear oil in lieu of a GL-5 lubricant that does contain sulphur and as
you correctly state is injurious to copper, brass, and the like.

Comment: I'm sorry, Mike ... how does this *in any way* answer the OP's question? Also, when posting an answer, please refrain from using abbreviations and local color. You may know what a g/box is, I can figure it out, but some others may not have a clue. (I know, g/box is an easy one, but I've seen many more you've left behind which has taken me a minute to understand). Remember, as well, punctuation, sentence structure, capitalization and spelling are you friend.

Comment: point well taken paulster-shall comply

Comment: Thanks for the response. So far no really clear answer but I did find thus link to be very useful: http://www.widman.biz/uploads/Transaxle_oil.pdf